# snap.data is not a function in onUpdate

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have two functions that trigger `onCreate` and `onUpdate` however, the `{uid}` in `onUpdate` is returning `undefined`, whilst `onCreate` returns the `{uid}`.

How can I get the `{uid}` to work for `onUpdate`?

**onUpdate.f.js** - `{uid}` is `undefined`

```
exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{uid}/alerts/{name}') //UID is the User ID value stored in alerts
  .onUpdate(snap => {
    const user = snap.data();
    console.log(user);
    const msg = {
      to: user.email,
      from: 'notifications@example.com',
      templateId: user.template,
      dynamic_template_data: {
        firstName: user.firstName,
        email: user.email,
        id: user.uid
      }
    };
    return sgMail.send(msg).catch(err => console.log(`${user.email} - ${err}`));
  });
```

**onCreate.f.js** - `{uid}` is correct

```
exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{uid}/alerts/{name}')
  .onCreate(snap => {
    const user = snap.data();
    console.log(user);
    const msg = {
      to: user.email,
      from: 'notifications@example.com',
      templateId: user.template,
      dynamic_template_data: {
        firstName: user.firstName,
        email: user.email,
        id: user.uid
      }
    };
    return sgMail.send(msg).catch(err => console.log(`${user.email} - ${err}`));
  });
```

**Fields in `doc` Alerts** from frontend

```
doCreateAlert = (id, email, firstName, lastName, alertType, transactionEmailId) => {
const db = this.firestore;
return db.doc(`users/${id}/alerts/${alertType}`).set({
    uid: id,
    name: alertType,
    email: email,
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    template: transactionEmailId,
    dateCreated: new Date(),
    dateModified: new Date()
  });
};
```

The onUpdate is triggered by updating the database with `onClick={this.updateAlert}` as

```
updateAlert = () => {
    const { firebase, userID } = this.props;
    const companyTypeSetup = db.doc(`users/${userID}/alerts/emailVerified`);
    companyTypeSetup.update({
      dateModified: new Date()
    });
  };
```

on the frontend I receive the error of

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No document to update: projects/app/databases/(default)/documents/users/undefined/alerts/emailVerified
```

and the function is never run. If I manually update the `doc` in Firestore, I get an error in the firebase functions log as

```
TypeError: snap.data is not a function
at module.exports.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate.snap (/user_code/lib/auth/onUpdate.f.js:17:23)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:754:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) shows, `onUpdate` has two parameters: `change` and `context`. You use `change` since you may want to access the value before the update or after the update. Assuming you want the value after the update, that would look like this:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{uid}/alerts/{name}') //UID is the User ID value stored in alerts
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const user = change.after.data();
    console.log(user);
    const msg = {
      to: user.email,
      from: 'notifications@example.com',
      templateId: user.template,
      dynamic_template_data: {
        firstName: user.firstName,
        email: user.email,
        id: user.uid
      }
    };
    return sgMail.send(msg).catch(err => console.log(`${user.email} - ${err}`));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Jen. One question I do have is the use of  `context`. What is it used for? From what I can see it is never defined or used? ESLint loves to tell me that.

Comment: @Darren `context` is commonly used to inspect the url parameters a Cloud function might be called with as the Firebase team points out in their documentation: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Answer (score 3):

Problem can easily be solved by reading the documents at [Handle Event Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). However, if you are like me and skim the documents then the solution is

```
.onUpdate(change => {
  const user = change.after.data();
```